# Background partial/sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 153417(8MB) on inserting huge data to SQLite

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-sqlite

I am developing an app for a certain for a certain shop. A shop has got almost 3883 customers (test data) and expected to be more than that. I am using Volley to fetch data to the app through `APIs`. After fetching the data from internet then store them to the local Database (`SQLite`) for future usage.

But during fetching the data i.e. sync from internet and storing them to local db.. the app hangs for almost 1 minute during saving them to local database. Sometimes i may lead to ANR's.

After looking on logs i got this messages.

[image]

I don't know what to do right now. Cause i tried to make those request i.e. Long running one to work on background with `ExcutorServices` but still the problem persist.

Look at this

```
ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().executeTask(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            db1.deletepartymaster();

            //-----API call for using volley method for login-----//
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    clsCommon.BASE_URL + "/endpoint",
                    new Response.Listener<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                System.out.println("response" + response);
                                int i ;
                                PartyMasterDetails party = null;
                                ArrayList<PartyMasterDetails> partylist = new ArrayList<PartyMasterDetails>();
                                JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("PartyMasterDetails");

                                for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                                    party = gson.fromJson(dataobj.toString(),PartyMasterDetails.class);

                                    partylist.add(party);
                                    //Log.d("PartMasterDetails-","PartMaster-:" + String.valueOf(partylist));
                                    //-----insert data-----/
                                    //db1.insertpartymasterdetails(party,userid);
                                    db1.insertpartymasterdetails(partylist,userid);
                                }


                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                        {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
            {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("UserId", userid);
                    params.put("CmpGuid", cmpguid);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        }
    });
```

What could be the best way to do such a thing in order to avoid such a problem. You may propose a best way to make that think work like i want to cause sometimes i can think about `Firebase Database` or not to save the to local DB. But i need a user of the app to do operations fast without lagging.

Comment: Can you tell us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: i need to know if the approach of using firebase will keep me saway from the problem

Comment: Have you tried something to check that?

Comment: I tried but it is same same. May be i don't know how i must send them

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. I now understand the basic logic on volley. By default volley on sending request to API's it will be on the background thread but onResponseor or onErrorResponse the thread change to main thread so as we can populate datas to UI. So what i did is do those long running operation on the background thread after the response. So i changed the codes like this and it is not hanging anymore.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            clsCommon.BASE_URL + "/endpoint",
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                   //BACK TO MAIN THREAD
                   ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().executeTask(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                   //SEND TO BACKGROUNDTHREAD
                           db1.deleteData();

                           try {
                               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                               System.out.println("response" + response);
                               int i ;
                               PartyMasterDetails party = null;
                               ArrayList<PartyMasterDetails> partylist = new ArrayList<PartyMasterDetails>();
                               JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("reponseData");

                               for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                   JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                   GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                                   Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                                   party = gson.fromJson(dataobj.toString(),PartyMasterDetails.class);
                                   db1.inserData(party,userid);
                               }

                               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                           catch (JSONException e)
                           {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                   });
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserId", userid);
            params.put("guid", cmpguid);
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

You can upvote my answer. Cheers !!